# How to Auto Size a button to smaller size?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a button with AutoSize true. I dynamically set the text to a big word. Then the button AutoSize correctly, but then I set the text to a small word. In this case, the button still with the same size, so the button gets bigger than its text.

My solution to solve this was this:

```
button.AutoSize = false;
button.AutoSize = true;
```

This code sux! Is there a descent solution?

I also tried `button.Refresh` and `button.Update`.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Resizing buttons (unless they're on a toolbar) violates the basic design principle of predictability. Users generally don't like it when things move around on dialogs (or windows) when they're working with them.

Comment: depending of a row selected in a grid, I want to change the text of a button to "Release" and "Lock" for example.

Comment: That shouldn't require you to resize the button. Set it to the standard button size and leave it at that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the `AutoSizeMode` to `GrowAndShrink` (the default is `GrowOnly`).

Comment: I also tried that, but the button height becomes too small. :S

Comment: Use the `MinimumSize` property to set the height.  Autosizing will respect that minimum height.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the button width to zero or something small in between turning autosize off and back on again.  I haven't tested this, but thought it would be worth a shot.

Comment: when AutoSize property is true, it ignores the Width property =-)